# Allow access to directory and content only for internal IP

Tags: nginx

I want to restrict access to a directory called `orders` on my Magento 2 website using NginX. It's located in the /pub/orders. I want to allow only my internal IP.

Here is what I've got:

```
location ~ /orders/.*? {
   allow x.x.x.x;
   deny all;
}
```

It's giving 403 forbidden for everyone, which is what I expected. However, when I add my IP, and navigate to, for example, `mysite.com/orders/file.php` it downloads the file...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your php extension is not runned as such, this is a nginx's error, not a IP restriction error

Comment: you can try this, location ^~ /foo/ {
    allow 1.2.3.4;
    deny all;
    }

Comment: @VijayMuddu still downloads it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set up PHP-FPM with nginx so Nginx executes the php files instead of serving them as downloads.

Try here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25591040/nginx-serves-php-files-as-downloads-instead-of-executing-them

Comment: Wow, that's harder than I thought it is...

Comment: @BareFeet in my experience Apache plays nicely with PHP out of the box, but it also adds a lot of stuff I don't need so I usually take the time to configure nginx. I think the performance benefits are worth it, and I think nginx is easier to configure.

Comment: I managed to sort that out, need to practise a bit me :p Thank you for your help :)